# How can I get the "Diamonds to you!" achievement in single player?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you get the "Diamonds to you!" achievement if you're in single player?

Comment: I don't know why this question has got downvoted. I upvoted this question because it is a questionthat can be written by everybody. It's just a question by a starter. Please, be good people with the starter people.

Answer (score 6):

On singleplayer, you can get the achievement by throwing a diamond at a zombie or skeleton capable of picking up items.

Not all zombies and skeletons are capable of picking up items, it's a random chance upon them spawning, so you may need to try a few before you find one that can.